# How to find function $g(x)$ for limit comparison test for improper integrals

Tags: calculus

I have a complicated problem. I should use a limit comparison test, but cannot decide with which function $g(x)$ I should compare my function $f(x)$
Here is the problem.

$$\int_0^\pi\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{x\ln(1+x)}dx$$

Answer (score 2):

Set $g(x)=\frac{1}{x}$. We know that $\int_0^\pi\frac{1}{x}\mathop{dx}$ diverges.

Now,

\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{x\ln(1+x)}\cdot\frac{x}{1}\\&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{\ln(1+x)}\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{\frac1{1+x}}&\text{by l'Hopital}\\
&=2
\end{align*}

Therefore, $\int_0^\pi \frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{x\ln(1+x)}\mathop{dx}$ diverges.